# Showing photon's spin from Maxwell equations

Tags: electromagnetism

We know, photon is a spin 1 particle. In other words, it means that a photon of some particular frequency carries an angular momentum of one unit.

Can this fact be somehow shown that photon, or an em wave must have some one unit angular momentum, just using the classical electromagnetism, or the maxwell equations?

Comment: This is conjecture but I don't think you would be able to derive this from classical EM without laying on some QM and going from there.

Comment: Photons are quantum mechanical particles/entities. Maxwell's equations are classical. There exists a quantized version of Maxwell's equation that can give the photon wave function,  http://cds.cern.ch/record/944002?ln=en . Note the photon does not have a frequency, it has an energy  hν  where ν is the frequency of  the classical electromagnetic wave it builds up as a quantum mechanical superposition with zillions of other photons.

Answer (score 2):

Although individual photons require quantum mechanics, in the classical limit of a very large number of these there should be spin angular momentum. Beth et al. Demonstrated in 1935 that circularly polarized light indeed has angular momentum corresponding to $E/\omega$ as for individual photons.

To derive this property from Maxwell's equations will be hard. Spin is a problem for the gauge theory of electromagnetism because the expression of spin is gauge dependent. The proper way to deal with photon spin is to treat it as a separately conserved quantity. The Noether theorem then implies that there must by a corresponding symmetry of the Lagrangian. The commonly used Belinfante lagrangian does not have this symmetry. I solve this problem and some  related paradoxes in my paper, accessible at https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0106078.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is some connection to the photons 2 different polarizations. Which can be easily obtained from maxswell equations.